# How to get bundle IDs of all installed applications without a jailbreak

Tags: ios, bundle-identifier

I need to know what applications are installed on the iDevice without a Jailbreak. I tryed different methodes, this seems to be the best, but it wont work on iOS 7.

```
BOOL APCheckIfAppInstalled(NSString *bundleIdentifier)
{
    static NSString *const cacheFileName = @"com.apple.mobile.installation.plist";
    NSString *relativeCachePath = [[@"Library" stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Caches"] stringByAppendingPathComponent: cacheFileName];
    NSDictionary *cacheDict = nil;
    NSString *path = nil;
    // Loop through all possible paths the cache could be in
    for (short i = 0; 1; i++)
    {

        switch (i) {
            case 0: // Jailbroken apps will find the cache here; their home directory is /var/mobile
                path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: relativeCachePath];
                break;
            case 1: // App Store apps and Simulator will find the cache here; home (/var/mobile/) is 2 directories above sandbox folder
                path = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"../.."] stringByAppendingPathComponent: relativeCachePath];
                break;
            case 2: // If the app is anywhere else, default to hardcoded /var/mobile/
                path = [@"/var/mobile" stringByAppendingPathComponent: relativeCachePath];
                break;
            default: // Cache not found (loop not broken)
                return NO;
            break; }

        BOOL isDir = NO;
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: path isDirectory: &isDir] && !isDir) // Ensure that file exists
            cacheDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path];

        if (cacheDict) // If cache is loaded, then break the loop. If the loop is not "broken," it will return NO later (default: case)
            break;
    }

    NSDictionary *system = [cacheDict objectForKey: @"System"]; // First check all system (jailbroken) apps
    if ([system objectForKey: bundleIdentifier]) return YES;
    NSDictionary *user = [cacheDict objectForKey: @"User"]; // Then all the user (App Store /var/mobile/Applications) apps
    if ([user objectForKey: bundleIdentifier]) return YES;

    // If nothing returned YES already, we'll return NO now
    return NO;
}

BOOL APCheckIfAppInstalled(NSString *bundleIdentifier); // Bundle identifier (eg. com.apple.mobilesafari) used to track apps

    NSArray *bundles2Check = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"com.apple.mobilesafari", @"com.my.application", @"com.blahblah.nonexistent", nil];

    for (NSString *identifier in bundles2Check)

        if (APCheckIfAppInstalled(identifier))

            NSLog(@"App installed: %@", identifier);

        else

            NSLog(@"App not installed: %@", identifier);
```

Comment: hi David G. have you got a solution Pease??

Comment: Nope, sorry. I don't have an answer yet

Answer (score 0):

All of these methods will be rejected if you submit the app for approval to Apple. Also all applications are installed in their own sandbox, meaning that they cannot do anything outside their own application. So without jailbreak, using documented APIs (You have no permission to access `NSHomeDirectory()`) and taking sandboxing into account, there is no way to do it.

Comment: I dont like to submit the app to the AppStore